# What cpu upgrade choices do I have?

Tags: processor

Trying to find out what cpu upgrades I could possibly do for my Toshiba satellite l675d, everything I read made sense then I read more and now I'm just confused. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

That computer uses generation 4 (the final generation) of Socket S1.  There's a complete list of processors which can be used on your board [on this site.](http://www.cpu-world.com/Sockets/Socket_S1_(S1g4).html)

Please note that nearly all of these CPUs are going to be, effectively, a lateral change (especially now).  An upgrade for that computer is basically a new computer.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading the CPU on a laptop is near impossible. Even if you could physically replace the CPU with another socket-compatible model, there is no guarantee it would work. Laptops are not designed to be upgraded, so consequently, OEMs can heavily lock down the hardware and the firmware - it is entirely possible that your machine is geared entirely to the original CPU, thus even if a new chip worked, it would not be able to realise the expected improvements.

And again, even if you could do this, the benefit would be near-neglible. When you are facing an army of modern tanks, replacing your horse with a better horse won't do you any good!

The tech on this laptop is obsolete, so either work within it's limited capability or put it out of its misery and buy a modern replacement.s